# Using Rouché theorem to analyze the image set

Tags: complex-analysis

**Problem:** For $f(z) = 6z^6 - 2z^2 + 1$ show $B_4(1) \subseteq f\left( B_1(0) \right)$.

It is claimed that this can be solved using Rouché's theorem, but I can't see how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have to show that for each $w \in B_4(1)$ the function $z\mapsto f(z)-w$ has a zero in $B_1(0)$.

Let $w\in B_4(1)$. Let $g(z) = 6z^6-2z^2$

Then for $|z| = 1$ the following holds:

$|f(z)-w - g(z)| = |6z^6-2z^2+1-w - (6z^4-2z^2)| = |1-w| < 4 = |6z^6|-|2z^2|$

$\leq |6z^6-2z^2| = |g(z)|$.

Hence, using Rouché's theorem, $g$ and $f-w$ have the same amount of zeros in $B_1(0)$. Since $g(0) = 0$, $f-w$ must have at least one.